# Run Tensorflow unit tests for a single file, but output nothing

Tags: unit-testing, tensorflow, testing, bazel

I want to run unit test for a single file in TensorFlow. I use this command:

`bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test`

But the result is:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/unique_op_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.528s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1
Executing tests from //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running main() from test_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test suites.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

And this:

```
bazel test -c opt  //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test
```

the output is:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
Target //tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/unique_op_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.985s, Critical Path: 0.13s
INFO: 1 process: 1 local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//tensorflow/core/kernels:unique_op_test                                 PASSED in 0.1s

INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

It seems that no test is run. Is there any option missing ？

I don't edit the source code file. The version of TensorFlow I use is 1.15 and the Bazel is 0.26.1

Comment: what if you use `bazel test` instead of `bazel run`?

Comment: @piarston After I replaced it with ```bazel test```, it was still running very quickly, seems that no tests were run. I put the output detail in the question

Comment: According to your log, the test was run (PASSED in 0.1s)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. There are `BENCHAMRK`s in unique_op_test.cc, not `TEST`s. In order to run benchmarks, `--benchmark_filter=` flag is needed. Relevant source code in `tensorflow/core/platform/test_main.cc`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no TEST or TEST_F functions in unique_op_test.cc, so no test will run. Some Benchmark functions there, and you can write your own TEST functions like what the benchmark functions do.